# By mistakenly deleted some microsoft files

Tags: uninstallation

I wanted to uninstall visual studio from my system. I happen to watch a video regarding in that. I performed all the steps as told in that video.

But when at a particular instant, I wanted to run an application using run as administrator, but i was not able to perform it. I thought to check its comment section. There I found that that video was a scam and i was deleting some essential files that too permanently.

The files I deleted are Microsoft.NET folder, Microsoft SDK's, Microsoft SQL server 'some year(2013)' localDB,  and Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 to2019 redistributable(x86).

I wanted to ask - Would these files hamper my system? if yes what should i Do?

I have tried recovering it from recycle bin and file history but was not able to restore it.